# How to apply for loop using python to avoid manual repeating

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, python-3.5, repeat

I have written a code which is a manual way,I need to automate it using for loop,but I am unable to do so,How do I write a for loop for the code given below:

This code is just a manual code.

I want to apply for loop to avoid manual process..

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
#import argparse
#import imutils
import cv2

img1="express.png"
img2="horizon.png"
img3="jazz.png"
img4="porter.png"
img5="westjet.png"
img6="e1.png"


# load the two input images
imageA = cv2.imread(img1)
imageB = cv2.imread(img2)
imageC = cv2.imread(img3)
imageD = cv2.imread(img4)
imageE = cv2.imread(img5)
imageF = cv2.imread(img6)


resized_imageA = cv2.resize(imageA, (256, 162))
resized_imageB = cv2.resize(imageB, (256, 162))
resized_imageC = cv2.resize(imageC, (256, 162)) 
resized_imageD = cv2.resize(imageD, (256, 162))
resized_imageE = cv2.resize(imageE, (256, 162))
resized_imageF = cv2.resize(imageF, (256, 162))     

#print (resized_imageA.shape)
#print (resized_imageB.shape)
#print (resized_imageC.shape)
#print (resized_imageD.shape)
#print (resized_imageE.shape)
#print (resized_imageF.shape)

# convert the images to grayscale
grayA = cv2.cvtColor(resized_imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(resized_imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayC = cv2.cvtColor(resized_imageC, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayD = cv2.cvtColor(resized_imageD, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayE = cv2.cvtColor(resized_imageE, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayF = cv2.cvtColor(resized_imageF, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


# compute the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between the two
# images, ensuring that the difference image is returned
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))

(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayC, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))

(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayD, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))

(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayE, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))

(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayF, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))
```

I want to apply for loop to avoid manual process.

Comment: use the concept of the dictionary, It will help you.

Comment: I am new in this..I have no idea how to do this..Could you please help how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import cv2
import glob
cv_img = []
imgs = glob.glob("*.png")
#imgs = ["express.png", "horizon.png", "jazz.png", "porter.png", "westjet.png", "e1.png"]

grays = []
for img in imgs:
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (256, 162))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grays.append(gray)

grayA, *other_grays = grays  # We could also do grayA, other_grays = grays[0], grays[1:]

for gray in other_grays:
    (score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, gray, full=True)
    diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8") # We don't use the diff value anywhere
    print("SSIM: {}".format(score))
```

The idea is to loop over some container, in this case a list containing filenames.  Every time you find yourself duplicating code (writing the same lines over and over again), you should attempt to encapsulate it behind a layer of abstraction.  In this case, instead of processing each file individually, you instead come up with a sequence of actions for processing a single file, and then apply that sequence to each file in turn.

Comment: Thanks a lot...:)

Comment: How to use globe library to take image file?

Comment: @Shaon Do you mean [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)?

Comment: globe is a library I guess...What I want is in the code above for 2nd line imgs = ["express.png", "horizon.png", "jazz.png", "porter.png", "westjet.png", "e1.png"] if I want to pick any image without giving the name of the file how to do that?

Comment: @Shaon I'm not familiar with that library.  You should ask another question, for visibility.

Comment: in the imgs dictionary image files are defined by their name,but if i just want to pull the images without using their name then how to do that?

Comment: any other way to do that?

Comment: [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) looks to be what you're looking for.  Something like `imgs = glob.glob('*.png')`

Comment: It's worth noting that `glob` returns matches in an arbitrary order, and that the code above treats the first file it processes differently from the others in the second loop.

Comment: I have editted the above code with globe library..Thanks for all your help Patrick..:)